# How to configure Textmate (Mac version) to run Stata commands?

Tags: command, textmate, stata

I'm a Mac user trying to configure Textmate to run Stata commands.

I downloaded and installed the Stata bundle from this website (http://bylr.net/3/2010/10/stata-bundle-for-textmate/)

Here's what I see in the Textmate Bundle Editor:

[image: Textmate Bundle Editor-STATA]

Here's where I get stuck.

I don't see any command for running Stata codes in the menu list. Did I download the right bundle? How do I run Stata commands in Textmate? I'm a beginner in Textmate. Am I to run something in the Terminal?

Comment: It would be a good idea to say if any of the answers below satisfy you.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to execute Stata code from within TextMate as you do with R, for example. Workarounds:

1. Run Stata code from the Terminal instead (and I guess that you could program TextMate to tell Terminal to tell Stata to run some code, but that's insane), as explain in Richard's answer.
2. Use the Tim Beatty bundle to send code to Stata and execute from there. There's what I think is [a better bundle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/statatmbundle/) by Phil Schumm over at SourceForge.

Answer (score 0):

From Stata's console you can run a do file with `do my_do_file` or from terminal.app you can run Stata in batch mode with `stata -b do my_do_file &`.

I don't see TextMate on the Stata text editor [FAQ](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/t/textEditors.html#mac), but the FAQ may provide the hints you need to make the TextMate bundle more robust.